# realloc can not access to the new size from other function

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, realloc

Im trying to increase the size of a `**array` with `realloc` which I have created with `malloc`.
I committed the `**array` to a function where I would like to increase the size.
Here is the part which increase the size:

```
imginf->height = imginf->height * 2;
imginf->width = imginf->width * 2;

array = realloc(array, imginf->height * sizeof(d*));
for(int i = 0; i < imginf->height; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(imginf->width * sizeof(d));
}
```

After that, I fill the array with two for loops. Everything works fine!

In the next function I try to save that array in a file. Here I use also two for loops.
With the first for loop I walk through the height and here I get the problem.

If the loop counter is `(imginf->height /2)` I ran out of the array. For the width everything’s works fine.

What went wrong? Especially, why could I fill the array?

**Edit**

Here the function definition for saving:

```
void Save(char * newname, inf imginf, d **array);
```

d is a struct with 3 unsigned chars.

Here the definition for the realloc function:

```
void reallocBig(inf *imginf, d **array);
```

Greetz.

Comment: Please show your function signatures.  It sounds like you're having a pass-by-value problem.

Comment: Please see my **Edit**, is that what you mean? Enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is a pass-by-value language.  Your `reallocBig` function can't modify the value of the array in the caller.  You need to change it to take a `d ***` parameter, and "fill in" that pointer in the function:

```
void reallocBig(inf *imginf, d ***array)
{
 ...
   *array = realloc(...)
   for (...)
      (*array)[i] = ...
 ...
}
```

The C FAQ has a [question about precisely your problem](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).  You should also note that your current implementation leaks all of the previous entries in the array.

Comment: Ohhhhhh yea you are so right :). I did it the hole time for `inf`... Thanks, I did not see my mistake.